# how to test Recaptcha with jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, recaptcha

I am using validate jquery plugin and recaptcha for a contact form and i woudld like to know how can i check if the code in the captcha is correct before the form get submitted if not send an error message because right now validate everything but i inserted a wrong code the form get submitted anyway. Here's my code ty in advance for anyhelp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
             var RecaptchaOptions = {
                lang : 'en',
                theme : 'custom',
                custom_theme_widget: 'recaptcha_widget'
             };
            </script>

            <form id="contact" method="post" action="#">

                <fieldset>
                    <label for="name_contact">NAME</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name_contact" name="name_contact" value="" placeholder="" minlength="2">

                    <label for="email_contact">EMAIL</label>
                    <input type="email" class="input-xlarge" id="email_contact" name="email_contact" value="" placeholder="">

                    <label for="telephone">CONTACT NUMBER</label>
                    <input type="tel" class="input-xlarge" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="" value="" >

                    <label for="message">MESSAGE</label>
                    <textarea id="message" class="input-xlarge" name="message" placeholder="" rows="5"></textarea>                  

                    <div id="recaptcha_widget" style="display:none">

                        <div id="recaptcha_image"></div>
                        <div class="recaptcha_only_if_incorrect_sol" style="color:red">Incorrect please try again</div>

                        <span class="recaptcha_only_if_image">Enter the words above:</span>
                        <span class="recaptcha_only_if_audio">Enter the numbers you hear:</span>

                        <input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" />

                        <div><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()">Get another CAPTCHA</a></div>
                        <div class="recaptcha_only_if_image"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio')">Get an audio CAPTCHA</a></div>
                        <div class="recaptcha_only_if_audio"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('image')">Get an image CAPTCHA</a></div>

                        <div><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.showhelp()">Help</a></div>

                    </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript"
                        src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Lf8RN4SAAAAAKnllVnDw23UpBIuAIdTRFgN1kmX">
                    </script>

                    <noscript>
                        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Lf8RN4SAAAAAKnllVnDw23UpBIuAIdTRFgN1kmX" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
                        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
                        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">
                    </noscript>             

                    <button type="submit" value="" id="" name="send" class="pull-right lightblue btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
                    </fieldset>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#contact").validate({
            rules: {
                "name_contact": {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                "email_contact":{
                    required: true
                },
                "message":{
                    required:true
                },
                "recaptcha_response_field":{
                    required:true
                }

            },
            messages: {
                "name_contact": {
                    required: "Please, enter a name"
                },
                "email_contact":{
                    required: "Enter a valid email"
                },
                "message":{
                    required: "Please provide a comment"
                },
                "recaptcha_response_field":{
                    required: "Captcha is required"
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.insertBefore(element);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's being submitted anyway because of `value="manual_challenge"` within the `name="recaptcha_response_field"` input.  Integration with captcha is possible but it's also specific to the captcha system.  Please construct a jsFiddle simulation of your form including the captcha portion.

Comment: @Sparky here's my file http://jsfiddle.net/9XXHE/

Comment: This requires a complex solution involving both jQuery and your server-side script.  My answer below only addresses the jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no simple solution only using JavaScript or jQuery.  Since you have to compare the Re-Captcha code using the API along with your *private* key, for proper security, you **must** do this process with some **server**-side code.

1. User fills out form correctly except for Re-Captcha code.
2. If Re-Captcha code is blank, normal `required` rule in jQuery Validate triggers a "missing Captcha" message.  User can try again.
3. A Re-Captcha code entered (correctly or incorrectly), form is submitted to your **server**-side code via jQuery `ajax` within the `submitHandler` callback function.
4. Your **server**-side code, PHP, Perl, whatever, then uses your private API key to verify the entered Re-Captcha code against the Re-Captcha code expected by the API.
5. If Re-Captcha code is correct, your **server**-side code continues as normal and returns a "success" text response to your jQuery `ajax` `success` callback function.
6. If Re-Captcha code is *incorrect*, your **server**-side code will *only* return an "error" text response to your jQuery `ajax` `success` callback function, and the server-side code will do nothing else.
7. Within your jQuery `ajax` `success` callback function, read the message text returned from the server-side code.
8. If the returned message indicates a success, then your form was already submitted successfully and you can redirect, clear out the form, do an animation, print a message, do nothing, or whatever, etc.
9. If the returned message indicates failure, generate a new Re-Captcha code via JavaScript, display an error message, *"incorrect Captcha entered"*, and the user can simply try again.

---

This is how I did mine...  you'll need to do something very much like the following.

Add a `submitHandler` to your `.validate()` options and use `ajax` to control the form submission.  It's the only way you can interact with the Captcha and control form submission.

You'll also need to modify your server-side function to test whether the captcha passed or failed, do the appropriate function, and to return the proper `ajax` message, `msg`.  Without knowing anything about your server-side code, it's impossible to say anything more specific.

(**NOTE:**  any solution that is purely JavaScript/jQuery, without editing your server-side code, is **not** secure.  Captcha can be easily bypassed and your private API key is exposed to the public.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#contact").validate({
        // your other options and rules,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                url: 'formMail.pl', // <-- whatever your server-side script, mine is a perl form mailer
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg.indexOf('captcha') != -1) {
                        Recaptcha.reload(); // reloads a new code
                        $('#recaptcha_response_field').before(msg); // error message
                    } else {
                        // anything else to do upon success, animations, etc.
                        // form was already submitted as per ajax
                    }
                }
            });
            return false; // blocks normal form submit
        }
    });

});
```

The following is only a PERL example of how I modified my server-side code which was a Form Mailer script.  You'll have to adapt your server-side code in some similar fashion.

The subroutine `check_captcha` is called when the script first runs.

```
sub check_captcha {     
       my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
       my $result=$ua->post(
           'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify',
           {
               privatekey => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',  # insert your private key here
               remoteip   => $ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'},
               challenge  => $Form{'recaptcha_challenge_field'},
               response   => $Form{'recaptcha_response_field'}
           }
       );

       if ( $result->is_success && $result->content =~ /^true/) {
               return;  # OK - continue as normal with Form Mailer
       } else {
               # error, Form Mailer will not continue
               &error('captcha_failed'); # failed Captcha code, call error subroutine to print an error message (msg) containing the word "captcha"
       }
}
```

Remember that this server-side code **must** return a message that your jQuery picks up within your jQuery `ajax` `success` callback as `msg` above.  In my example, if the message contains the word "captcha", that means the code was entered wrong and user must re-enter a new Captcha code.

Comment: ty @Sparky for your answers, before you post this solution i tried this: I erased the script and the none script after the id="recaptcha_widget" div and use some code from the example captcha file that is in the folder when u download the recaptchalib.php, so now the code it's working when u digit a wrong code, the form gets clean and u have fill the inputs again until u got the right asnwer, I wanted to ask you, if u think this is save? let me post the code in the next comment ty in advance for any answer

Comment: <?php
require_once('captcha/recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "x"; 
$privatekey = "x";
$resp = null;
$error = null;
if ($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]) {
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
        if ($resp->is_valid) {echo "You got it!";} else { $error = $resp->error; }
}
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);           
?>

Comment: @paoloi, Yes... as long as your keys are stored in your PHP code, this is safe.  Nobody can access the raw PHP code from the public side.

Comment: ty very much @Sparky now i have another question.

Comment: i used this example http://www.darksideofthecarton.com/2008/12/15/validating-recaptcha-jquery-ajax/comment-page-2/#comment-23170 and combined it with yours so my submit handler is like this  this file is not working but at least give an idea of what im doing http://jsfiddle.net/EaSTa/ the form validation is fine my only problem is that the captcha validation always return the error message, any idea?...and sorry for so much questions, ty again

Comment: @paoloi, I see that this line: `submitHandler: function validateCaptcha(){` should be `submitHandler: function(form){`.  Otherwise, it's impossible for me to troubleshoot your server-side code... that part is up to you.  I know my posted answer is working for me.  Also check the value of `html` coming back from server with a `console.log(html);`

Comment: i really dont understand your example, i know it is me, dont know exactly how this is done

Comment: @paoloi, I don't know how I can make it more clear.  What part don't you understand?  What about the rest of my comment?  The incorrect `function(form)` and my questions about the message coming from your server?