# Google reCaptcha + custom form validation: Can I run .execute() synchronous?

Tags: jquery-validate, recaptcha, synchronous, ajaxform

I use [reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#programmatic_execute)+[validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation) jQuery plugin:

```
<script>
  $('#contact_us-form').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      grecaptcha.execute(); //How to run this syncly?
      $(form).ajaxSubmit({ ... }); // This request without token
    }
  });
</script>
<form>
    ...
    <div class='g-recaptcha' ... />
</form>
```

This code almost works. Almost because `execute` is run async and response is come after `ajaxSubmit` submits form data.

The work around is to assign `callback` property for `g-recaptcha` and move `ajaxSubmit` into that callback:

```
var my_callback = function() {
  $(form).ajaxSubmit({ ... });
}

<div class='g-recaptcha' data-callback='my_callback'/>
```

But this looks hairly. Furthermore the `form` variable is not available from `my_callback` thus I can not reuse this call back between similar forms.

Is there a way to `execute` synchronously?

Comment: `submitHandler` only fires when the form is valid... however, if you have not verified reCaptcha yet, then the form is not valid.  My point?  The `submitHandler` might not be the best place for checking reCaptcha.

Comment: Another way is to do the reCaptcha check on your server-side instead of another ajax call to Google from the client.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15414279/594235

Comment: @Sparky: Yes. It fires before data is submitted to the server. There is no reason to bother google if form data is not validated. At `submitHandler` form is valid and before submitting it to our server we do last check: captcha.

Comment: @Sparky: that answer is outdated. We should do ajax call to Google to prevent bots make requests to our servers

Comment: Since asynchronous ajax calls are obviously a problem, then good luck to you.

Comment: Perhaps just stick with your "hairly" workaround, which should work as long as you fix the form selector.